# Get a byte array from gtop11dotnet.dll in c#

Tags: .net, smartcard, pkcs#11

I have a gtop11dotnet.dll. It is .NET PKCS#11 Library for Windows v2.2.0.9 from Gemalto website. DLL is containing C_GetCardProperty method which can be used to retrieve Smart card's serial number or GUID. According to PKCS#11 User's Guide and .NET Integration Guide it is "byte[] GetCardProperty(byte property, byte flags)". It receives two bytes as parameters and retrieves e.g. serial number or GUID in form of bytes array. 
My question is how to get serial number and store it into managed bytes array?

Here is my try:

```
[DllImport("gtop11dotnet.dll")]
public static extern byte[] C_GetCardProperty(byte property, byte flags);
public static void Main()
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[12];
    bytes = C_GetCardProperty(0x06, 0x00) //Error at this line -> Cannot marshal 'return value': Invalid managed/unmanaged type combination.
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

What is ".NET PKCS#11"? PKCS#11 v2.20 nor v2.30 draft do not contain "C_GetCardProperty" method. You are probably facing with some proprietary Gemalto/.NET thing that has nothing to do with PCKS#11 as known by the rest of the world and Gemalto does a "good" thing by prefixing arbitrary functions with "C_" and calling the result cryptoki. PKCS#11 is a C interface and has nothing to do with managed/unmanaged code or .NET.

Comment: Yes it is a proprietary Gemalto function. I downloaded it from [Gemalto website](http://www.gemalto.com/products/dotnet_card/resources/libraries.html?toggler=0), installed and got gtop11dotnet.dll in C:\Program Files\Gemalto\DotNet PKCS11. Inside that DLL there is C function C_GetCardProperty, I double checked it with Dependency Walker. But how to get serial number or GUID that the function returns?

Comment: Sorry, you need to ask Gemalto about it. Better yet - tell them to drop the function or rename it to Gemalto_GetCardProperty - abusing PKCS#11 will not lead to anything good.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

public static extern uint C_GetCardProperty(uint slotID, byte property, byte flags, byte[] blob, ref byte length);